# Erro ENUM Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize-js

Recebo o erro `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` na declaração do meu modelo. Segue código abaixo:

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize')

class Usuario extends Model {
    static init(sequelize) {
        Usuario.init({
            nome: DataTypes.STRING,
            nascimento: DataTypes.DATE,
            genero: DataTypes.ENUM('masculino', 'feminino'),
            email: DataTypes.STRING,
            disponibilidade: DataTypes.ENUM('presencial', 'online'),
            biografia: DataTypes.STRING,
            foto_perfil: DataTypes.STRING
        }, {sequelize})
    } 
}

module.exports = Usuario;
```

A mensagem de erro:

```
C:\Users\helde\Documents\TCC\node_modules\sequelize\lib\data-types.js:739
  constructor(...args) {
             ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at new ENUM (C:\Users\helde\Documents\TCC\node_modules\sequelize\lib\data-types.js:739:14)
    at Object.apply (C:\Users\helde\Documents\TCC\node_modules\sequelize\lib\utils\class-to-invokable.js:14:14)
    at Function.init (C:\Users\helde\Documents\TCC\src\models\Usuario.js:8:31)
    at Function.init (C:\Users\helde\Documents\TCC\src\models\Usuario.js:5:17)
    at Function.init (C:\Users\helde\Documents\TCC\src\models\Usuario.js:5:17)
    at Function.init (C:\Users\helde\Documents\TCC\src\models\Usuario.js:5:17)
    at Function.init (C:\Users\helde\Documents\TCC\src\models\Usuario.js:5:17)
    at Function.init (C:\Users\helde\Documents\TCC\src\models\Usuario.js:5:17)
    at Function.init (C:\Users\helde\Documents\TCC\src\models\Usuario.js:5:17)
    at Function.init (C:\Users\helde\Documents\TCC\src\models\Usuario.js:5:17)
```

Answer (score 1):

Este erro acontece por que você está chamando `.init()` na classe `Usuario` de forma recursiva em `Usuario.init(...)`, logo isto entra e loop infinito e gera este erro.

O erro não tem haver com `ENUM`, mantenha o código de tipos como está.

O correto seria você chamar `super.init()`, que é para iniciar o `Model` e não a própria classe `Usuario`.

Tente desta forma:

```
class Usuario extends Model {
    static init(sequelize) {
        super.init({
            nome: DataTypes.STRING,
            nascimento: DataTypes.DATE,
            genero: DataTypes.ENUM('masculino', 'feminino'),
            email: DataTypes.STRING,
            disponibilidade: DataTypes.ENUM('presencial', 'online'),
            biografia: DataTypes.STRING,
            foto_perfil: DataTypes.STRING
        }, {sequelize})
    } 
}
```

Comment: quando eu deixo assim e tendo usar uma função index para me retornar todos os usuarios do banco de dados da outro bug

(node:10908) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: Table 'dh_quero_materia.usuarios' doesn't exist

Comment: Pode criar outra pergunta e mostrar o log de erros? Vai ficar mais facil de ajudar. Agora tem que ver como está sendo criado a tabela de usuarios.

Answer (score 0):

```
    class Usuario extends Model {
    static init(sequelize) {
        super.init({
            nome: DataTypes.STRING,
            nascimento: DataTypes.DATE,
            genero: DataTypes.ENUM('masculino', 'feminino'),
            email: DataTypes.STRING,
            disponibilidade: DataTypes.ENUM('presencial', 'online'),
            biografia: DataTypes.STRING,
            foto_perfil: DataTypes.STRING,
            senha: DataTypes.STRING
        },  { sequelize ,
             tableName: 'usuario' },
        )
    }
}
```

erro foi resolvido adicionando a propriedade tableName: 'usuario'